# pip install in python 3.6.5

Tags: python, libraries

I'm trying to install some libraries on python, and I open cmd and type`-m pip install <lib_name>` but it says there's syntax error. When I skip the "`<`" it says `pip is not a recognized command`. Any help? I'm using Python 3.6.5.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L98pV.png)

this is the output for almost every command I'm trying...

Comment: What are you actually typing into `cmd`? 'When I skip the "<"', where is that in what you're typing?

Comment: What is the `-m`?

Comment: What version of `pip` are u using ? try running this command `pip --version`

Comment: try `python3 -m pip install <libname>`

Comment: check if pip (and python) are in your environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

first of all we need to know if you are good to go with pip.
Try posting the output of 
`pip --version`
If pip doesn't seem to be installed, you should install it via

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

Once pip is installed you can install packages using the command

```
pip install whatever
```

Here's a complete starter pack tutorial for using pip :)
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Answer (score 1):

you can enter either cmd into the terminal:

`python -m pip install <package-name>`
or
`pip install <package-name>`

The first will always install into your global environment and the second could depend on whether you're in a virtualenv (if none of this makes sense to you, don't worry about it).

Comment: I'm trying the second, but on python,org it said to write "-m pip install <package_name>

Answer (score 0):

First install python!

According to your screenshot, it is not installed... (or not available, in that case check your PATH in system properties).

Comment: I have. my friend has the same path and It works for her. I have installed python, idle works and all